# plot_ly barplot messes up the order on the x axis

Tags: r, shiny, plotly

When doing a bar plot with `shiny` + `plotly`, I stumbled on a weird output from plotly doing pca analysis graphs: when there are more than 9 `PC`'s on the X axis, it shows them in a weird order. See the sample and the output below:

```
colnames(rv$pca_prep$x)
     [1] "PC1"  "PC2"  "PC3"  "PC4"  "PC5"  "PC6"  "PC7"  "PC8"  "PC9"  "PC10" "PC11" "PC12"
rv$pca_explained
     [1] 0.278889072 0.132174191 0.114264338 0.090405125 0.081273614 0.078230246 0.064104021 0.060324481 0.046375086
    [10] 0.028577782 0.023676285 0.001705759
plot_ly(type = "bar", x = colnames(rv$pca_prep$x), y =rv$pca_explained)
```

[image: plot_ly output image]

After some research I figured out that that plotly probably uses lexographical scoping. Is there an easy way to change it into the needed numeric one? Is there an easy workaround? Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you try factor(rv$pca_prep$x) ? With ggplot you have to convert as a factor and change the order of the levels.

Comment: it will still probably sort the factor levels alphabetically by default. you can manually specify the order with `factor(colnames(rv$pca_prep$x), levels=colnames(rv$pca_prep$x))`

Comment: Will try in a minute.

Comment: @AdamSpannbauer Thank you, it doesnt seem elegant, but works as needed!

Comment: @AdamSpannbauer maybe you should post it as answer, so I can accept it as the right one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`plot_ly` is sorting your input to `x` the same way `base::sort` would.  Per @Sebastian'
s comment you can use `factor` in your `plot_ly` call to overcome this issue but by default `factor` will also have the same sort behavior.  You can use `factor`'s `levels` argument to specify the order of the factor levels and get your desired behavior.

```
#fake data with names similiar to question vars
pca_explained <- sort(abs(rnorm(12)), decreasing = TRUE)
col_names     <- paste0("P", seq_along(pca_explained))

#plotly call with factor(x, levels=x)
plotly::plot_ly(type = "bar", 
                x    = factor(col_names, levels=col_names), 
                y    = pca_explained)
```

#### output:

[image: plotly output]